# How to parse XML response with single tag

Tags: xml, parsing, go

This is my XML response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{"journalseq":"7002924","statuscode":"0002","statusdesc":"Date placed : Invalid Date","msgsockheader":["data","data"],"msgmwheader":["data","data"],"msgmbheader":["data","data"],"msgmbmessage":["data","data"]}</string>
```

as seen above, it only have one tag with struct inside it. i already make struct to parse it like this :

```
type Data struct {
        xml.Name `xml:"string"`
    }

    type DoMBASEHoldAmountResult struct {
        XMLName    xml.Name
        Data       Data
    }

    var soapEnvelope DoMBASEHoldAmountResult

    // parse for hold response
    xml.Unmarshal(input, &soapEnvelope)
```

but there's nothing inside soapEnvelope. i don't find any answer in stackoverflow, and all i can find is when there's many tag on the XML. how to unmarshall XML like that? Moreover, how can i just take some data to make my response? let's say i just want to take journalSeq and one data in array msgsockheader as my response, do i still have to parse everything, put it on struck, then from that struct i choose every value that i need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the root struct's (`DoMBASEHoldAmountResult`) xmlname matches the xml's root element name. And to unmarshal to contents of an element that's matched by a struct with an xml.Name field, you can use a `[]byte` or `string` field and the `innerxml` tag option.

```
type DoMBASEHoldAmountResult struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"string"`
    String  string   `xml:",innerxml"`
}

var soapEnvelope DoMBASEHoldAmountResult

// parse for hold response
if err := xml.Unmarshal(input, &soapEnvelope); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(soapEnvelope.String)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/l4Coz9habxa

Comment: I see, so we use innerxml to get data inside the tag. why we use comma? and if we want to separate that data should we make struct for it? and define all the xml tag?

Comment: To not confuse it for an element's name which is always supplied as the first item in the xml tag. I.e. if you did `xml:"innerxml"` then the `encoding/xml` package would look for the element `<innerxml>...</innerxml>`.

Comment: Ohh isee, thanks a lot.but it a litle bit waste that we must make the data byte then unmarshall it again to insert it to struct .